# How to get child node using context.expand in groovy?

Tags: groovy, soapui

everybody!

Using SoapUI 5.2.1 and Groovy
TestCase has 2 Test Steps:

1. SOAP Request "create"
2. Groovy Script

Inside the request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope ... >
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <ban:transactions>
   <session>x</session>
   <type>y</type>
  </ban:transactions>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope ... >
```

Inside script:

```
def xml = context.expand('${create#request#//ban:transactions}')
```

This script returns:

```
  <ban:transactions>
   <session>x</session>
   <type>y</type>
  </ban:transactions>
```

What should i change in script, so that script could return me:

```
   <session>x</session>
   <type>y</type>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? How are you going to use that data?

Comment: @Rao, i need that child node, because i'm going to compare it with the repeat transation, which has different parent tags - not  <ban:transactions>, but <ban:scheme>

Comment: Are you comparing one response with another? what is the use case?

Comment: Yes. So, we create transaction and want to repeat this transaction. My use case is to compare both - has back-end worked correctly and the tags are equal or not, because sometimes developers forgets to add different tags to repeat operation. For example, dev forgot to add <type>y</type> to response of repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your XML is and we will extract the data under the nodes body

```
<Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<Body>
<hello>oye1</hello>
<ok>test</ok>
 <hello>oye2</hello>
<ok>test2</ok>
</Body>
</Envelope>
```

The groovy code below can extract the nodes from an xml mentioning the node above it. So here we are trying to extract the nodes under  tag

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("testStepName#Response")
def  responseXml=holder.getXmlObject()
String xmlObj=responseXml.toString()
String [] responseXmlObj=xmlObj.split('<Body>')[1].split('</Body>')
log.info responseXmlObj[0]
```

output will come as

```
Thu Nov 23 12:38:05 GMT+05:30 2017:INFO:
<hello>oye1</hello>
<ok>test</ok>
<hello>oye2</hello>
<ok>test2</ok>
```

you will need to change testStepName with the name of the step which has the response

Comment: Thank you, that's helpfull!
I knew this way, but thought there's a shorter way using context.expand and xpath...

Comment: Thanks for marking it as answer. you may upvote it as well. It will be visible once you reach at certain level